# SQL Trigger not respecting where clause

Tags: sql-server, trigger

I have a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateTbl] 
   ON  [dbo].[TableB] 
   AFTER INSERT

AS 
BEGIN

       DECLARE @role varchar(20) 
       select @role = u.[role] from inserted i join users u on u.id = i.creator_id 

       if @role = 'client'
              update TableA
              set updated_date = i.created_date from inserted i where TableA.id = i.trans_id

       if @role = 'tech'
              update TableA
              set updated_date = i.created_date from inserted i where TableA.id = i.trans_id and i.[public] = 'true'



END
GO
```

But it doesn't work as expected. The updated_date is still updated with the value of i.created_date even if i.[public]='false'. Any idea?

Comment: Your trigger has been written as if the INSERT statement would insert only 1 row.

Comment: Another problem you're likely going to have... If you do a multi-row insert that has a mix of both "client" and "tech" users, You'll find that the @role will be arbitrarily set to one or the other and the corresponding update will be applied to the entire set.

Comment: thank you for your replies. I had an idea that this was the issue based on previous articles, but I'm having a hard time revising the query correctly. any suggestion on how to revise the query?

Answer (score 2):

When you `DECLARE` and `SELECT @role=` at the beginning of your code, you assume that the trigger will only be applied to single-row inserts. Effectively, the value of @role is not guaranteed, as it is assigned multiple times, and you cannot control the order.

To fix this, you could instead join the users table into your update:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.updated_date=i.created_date

FROM TableA AS a
INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON a.id=i.trans_id
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id=i.creator_id

WHERE u.[role]='client' OR
      u.[role]='tech' AND i.public='true';
```

In this example, the update is performed if a) the role is "client", *or* b) the role is "tech" and public is "true".